# Hibernate <set> key from joined table

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, set

I wonder if it's possible to define `Set` in Hibernate mapping in a such way, that  element would specify not column in original (**FOO**) table, but in joined one (**BAR**). Let's say we have some `FooContainer.hbm.xml`, which contains `Set` of `Foo` objects:

```
<set ...>
  <key column="COLUMN_FROM_BAR" />
  <one-to-many class="xyz.Foo" />
</set>
```

Here **FOO** has FK to **BAR** (**FOO.BAR_ID**), so joining is done through element in Foo.hbm.xml:

```
<many-to-one class="xyz.Bar" fetch="join" column="BAR_ID" foreign-key="barId" ... />
```

which results in joined **FOO-BAR** select whenever `xyz.Foo` is fetched.

Problem is that where condition of generated `Set` fetching select is something like:

```
... WHERE _FOO_0.COLUMN_FROM_BAR = ?
```

when desired one is:

```
... WHERE _BAR_0.COLUMN_FROM_BAR = ?
```

Comment: this doesn't make any sense: there would be no link between the two tables.

Comment: There is link in DB (FOO references BAR) and in hbm its defined in <many-to-one class="xyz.Bar" fetch="join" ... />. Details of this relation are missing because they are not related to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in [Java Persistence with Hibernate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394885)  (page 296). Trick is setting different set table (**BAR**) from target class (`Foo`):

```
  <set table="BAR" ...>
    <key column="COLUMN_FROM_BAR" /> 
    <many-to-many
      class="xyz.Foo"
      column="BAR_ID"
      unique="true"
      />
  </set>
```