# Referencing a joined entity when the foreign key column is on the joined table

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following class mappings:
Class Book:

```
Table("BOOKS")
Id(b => b.Id)
Join("BOOKS_EXTRA_INFO", j =>
    {
         j.Optional();
         j.References(b => b.Author);
    }
```

Class Author:

```
TABLE("AUTHORES")
Id(a => a.Id)
HasMany(a => a.Books).Table("BOOKS_EXTRA_INFO")
```

The problem with this mapping is that when I try to do the following:

```
var a = Session.Get<Author>(1);
```

The Books Collection is empty. I checked the SQL that NH generates and the problem is in the where clause:

```
Select ... WHERE BOOKS.AUTHOR_ID = 1
```

The correct Where clause should be:

```
Select ... WHERE BOOKS_EXTRA_INFO.AUTHOR_ID = 1
```

I found this question: [Hibernate <set> key from joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733902/hibernate-set-key-from-joined-table) which is really similar to (if not same as) my question, but the solution uses xml mappings, and I don't understand how to do the same in fluent mapping.

**I Can't change the DB schema.**

What is the correct fluent mapping for my problem?

**Edit:** Updated the mappings to show the exact mappings I have.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you linked specifies the table name on the set. This can be done in Fluent easily:

```
HasMany(a => a.Books).Table("BOOKS_EXTRA_INFO");
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have tried it already and it didn't help.
Could this be a bug in fluent nhibernate?

Comment: Have you checked the generated XML mappings if the table is specified there?